# What are the knowledge requirements for an aliyah?

Tags: torah-service, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef

In [Midrash Tanhuma Yitro 15](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Yitro.15.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), we read that Rabbi Akiva was called to "read the Torah" (**לִקְרוֹת בְּסֵפֶר תּוֹרָה**) before the congregation, but refused "because I have not reviewed the chapter two or three times, and no one is permitted to recite the words of the Torah until he has reviewed them two or three times by himself."

Now, was he called upon just "to read", in Hebrew with the proper vowels and cantillation, or should we also assume he was asked to give a dvar Torah on the portion?

I am asking: Can we accept an aliyah if we can read from the scroll, in Hebrew with the proper vowels and cantillation, but may not understand in depth what we are reading, with its many levels of meanings and associated commentaries?

Comment: Tosfot indeed quotes this requirement for Leining in Megillah 31b

Comment: Why do you think it's odd that R Akiva would turn down reading an Aliyah if he hadn't prepared the Leining?

Comment: Maurice - indeed, Shulchan Aruch does mention that the *oleh* should know how to read Hebrew, at least. Keep in mind, that the original public Torah reading was done by each *oleh*, and much of Shulchan Aruch conveys this concept. The designated *ba'al kri'ah* (Torah reader) is a significantly later concept. As for becoming more lenient in the requirement that the oleh be able to read Hebrew - that may be in some *teshuva* somewhere - have to hunt for that.

Comment: @DanF -- All I wanted to know is:  How much does the oleh have to understand, even beyond the meaning of the words?  Obviously he must know how to read Hebrew.  I asked: "are we really not allowed to accept an aliyah and read from the scroll unless we understand in depth what we are reading?"  (How should I have phrased it?)

Comment: He may know how to read Hebrew but who said he knew the vowels or the cantillation? He hadn't prepared so he didn't read the Torah...

Comment: @robev -- If he "knows how to read Hebrew [with] the vowels and the cantillation", but does not fully understand the passage, with its many levels of meanings and associated commentaries, is he allowed to go up or not?

Comment: Who said otherwise?

Comment: @DanF see misnayot bikkurim 3e chapter

Comment: Good exposition in https://anshesholomnewrochelle.org/sermons/what-is-involved-in-an-aliyah/

Answer (score 1):

SA OC 139.1

> במקום שנהגו שהעולה עצמו קורא בקול רם אם לא סידר תחלה הפרשה פעמים ושלש בינו לבין עצמו לא יעלה. ובמקום שהחזן קורא הוא צריך לסדר תחלה (בית יוסף): ‏
>
> The Shulchan Aruch needs only fluency in reading {as a musician needs to repeat the Music sheet, velocity, rythm and just cantilation}.

We can add as an explanation that if he prepared the reading good enough to read syntactically correct (nikud and Taamim, sufficient speed), there is no difference for people who are listening.